# How to make MousePosition more reliable

Tags: graphics, bugs, dynamic

This takes a little patience to reproduce, but I got a screenshot of it in version 9 on Mac OS X 10.7.5:

With a small `Graphics` object, it occasionally happens that `MousePosition` doesn't get updated when your mouse enters the graphic from the *bottom*.

```
Dynamic[MousePosition["Graphics"]]

Graphics[{Orange, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]}, ImageSize -> 60,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image: mouseposition]

As the image shows, the mouse is clearly inside the orange square, but the line above shows `None` instead of the mouse coordinates relative to the `PlotRange`. If I leave the square toward the top and re-enter from the top, the mouse position starts following my movements. To see the effect of the frozen `None` mouseposition, it seems I have to enter the rectangle from the bottom. I have to try this a couple of times - it doesn't happen every time.

Is there a way, perhaps by surrounding the `Graphics` command in some other environment, to insure that the `MousePosition` is recorded more reliably?

**Edit**

I've now reproduced it on *Mathematica* version 9 *and* 8.0.4, OS X 10.7.5 on two different computers.

**Edit 2**

Although I'm not 100% sure, I strongly believe that jVincent's observation is correct: to reproduce this, I have to set the zoom level of the notebook, or the Magnification setting in `Advanced Preferences > Global Preferences > Notebook Options > Display Options` to something *other than* the default `100 %` (or `1`, respectively). In my case, the latter was set to `1.25` when I made the screen shot.

Comment: Can't repro (fortunately). Mma 8.0 on WinXP

Comment: Can't reproduce in version 9 on win7 64-bit.

Comment: @Silvia So either it's Mac specific, or worse: hardware specific. I'm on a new Macbook Pro with retina display and NVidia Graphics card.

Comment: I can't reproduce either. Tried for a long time. Mac Book Pro, OS 10.8.2, AMD Radeon HD 6750M 1024 MB, Mathematica V9.

Comment: Hmm.. It's an NVidia here too (9800GTX). Hope it's not that bad..

Comment: Can't reproduce either. And I am on a Macbook Pro Retina too (NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024MB), OS 10.8.2, v9. Let me know if you want me to try something else

Comment: I have tried on a Mac Pro with OS 10.7.5, ATI Graphics card, Mathematica 8.0.4 but works fine.

Comment: can't reproduce it: Mma 8.0.4 Mac 10.6.8 Mac Mini. I will try V8 & V9 on my Macbook Pro in the morning.

Comment: Easily reproduced when screen magnification is anything except 100%. Windows 7, Mma 9, Intel HD 4000.

Comment: I could easily reproduce it, even with magnification 100%. Windows 7, Mma 8.0. Seems to depend on the speed with which the Graphic is entered.

Comment: @jVincent Yes indeed, although I had 100% zoom in the notebook, I had a Magnification setting of `1.25` in the Advanced Global Preferences. When I set that to 1, I don't get the flaky behavior anymore. That's an important clue.

Comment: @einbandi Yes, I think it happens more easily if I'm right below the box and then enter is slowly... but jVincent's comment about zoom level does seem to apply to me, too.

Comment: Repro'd with non-default zoom. V9 on OSX 10.8.2

Comment: I can reproduce the problem on my system (OS X 10.6.8, _Mathematica_ V9) even at the standard 100% magnification. It takes more tries at 100% than other magnifications, but it is still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this issue has been confirmed on several different operating systems and in *Mathematica* versions 8 and 9, it seems that it should be reported as a bug. I've done that [TS 2418].

In the meantime, one possible way to avoid the glitch is this:

```
Dynamic[MousePosition["Graphics"]]

Dynamic[p]

EventHandler[
 Graphics[{Orange, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]}, ImageSize -> 60, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}],
 "MouseMoved" :> (p = MousePosition["Graphics"])]
```

> `None`
>
> `{0.7, 0.02}`

[image: box]

The mouse in this snapshot was over the box (not captured in the shot), but its position again was not recorded by the first `Dynamic[MousePosition["Graphics"]]`.

However, the second output (`{0.7, 0.02}`) is the correct result. It is generated by `p = MousePosition["Graphics"]` as the handler for the `"MouseMoved"` event over the `Graphics` expression. Fortunately this event is triggered reliably, even when the first `MousePosition` doesn't get updated. So the assignment to `p` as a response to entering the graphic forces the update with the correct mouse coordinates.