# Delay of events detection dependent of "MouseDown" position

Tags: front-end, dynamic, gui-construction, eventhandler

Let's say we have a `Rectangle` with color which depends of `CurrentValue["MouseOver"]`:

```
Deploy@Framed@Graphics[
       Dynamic @ {If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Red, Green], Rectangle[]}
       , ImagePadding -> 10]
```

[image]

- With cursor over the `Rectangle[]` the color switches to `Red` as expected,
- also if one put the `"MouseDown"` and drag it around it is still `Red`,
- however if you put the `"MouseDown"` outside the rectangle, on the padded area, and drag it to the rectangle **it will not switch the color till `"MouseUp"`**.

**Is there any way to avoid such behaviour in general?**

I can create some workarounds for particular situations but I'm looking for a general solution. I was thinking about `EventHandler`'s `PassEvents` options but it seems it is a deeper problem (*I've failed with this approach :)*).

---

It looks like the problem is the `"MouseDown"` event is blocking some functions, for example:

- `Dynamic@CurrentValue["ControlKey"]` is not working while the mouse button is down.
- I've faced it before with `MouseAppearance`: [Problem MouseAppearance updating while “MouseDown”](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18123/5478)

Comment: It doesn't switch until MouseMoved after MouseUp. It's as if MouseMoved and MouseDragged are mutually exclusive, and MouseOver is only updated on MouseMoved?

Comment: @TimothyWofford I do not see this, only MouseUp is enough for switch in my case, maybe it's OS dependent? It seems rather that MouseDown is blocking some events detections, try: `Dynamic@CurrentValue["ControlKey"]` and press Ctrl when the Mouse is down.

Comment: @Kuba I belive that dynamic interactivity in general is halted during mouse down, at least that has always been my experience (With slider interactions and such being excluded). For instance try `DynamicWrapper[
 Dynamic[t], Refresh[t = AbsoluteTime[], UpdateInterval -> 0.1]
 ]`, and press the mouse button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original (incorrect) answer**

When you press in the white area and drag into the green square, you begin a selection just like when you select objects for copy-paste operations. The workaround I propose is to prevent the selection process to begin in the first place.

First way: Create the cell with the option `Selectable -> False`

```
CellPrint@Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes@
  Deploy@Framed@Graphics[
   Dynamic@{If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Red, Green], 
     Rectangle[]}, ImagePadding -> 10]
  ], Selectable -> False]
```

Second way: If the cell is already created, press `Ctrl+Shift+E` and edit the cell options to include `Selectable -> False`, press `Ctrl+Shift+E` again.

**Update**

The following code should produce the result you want:

```
CellPrint@Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes@
  Framed@Graphics[
    Dynamic@{If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Red, Green], 
      Rectangle[]}, ImagePadding -> 10]
  ], Selectable -> False]
```

Comment: Mmm ... it works only if you begin from outside the padded area. So, the above is not an answer, yet. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Hector now it works :) thanks, it seems `Deploy` is messing around a little.

Comment: @Kuba: the strange thing is that `Deploy` is supposed to [disable](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Deploy.html) selection.

Comment: @Kuba: I think the problem is that `ContentSelectable -> False` does not change the properties of the frame.

Comment: @Hector It seems it is really what it is all about. It even helps with `DynamicWrapper[ Dynamic[t], Refresh[t = AbsoluteTime[], UpdateInterval -> 0.1] ]`