# Passing mouse related events broken by Deploy / Deployed->True

Tags: graphics, bugs, front-end, dynamic

**Bug reproduced in V9.0.1  and fixed in V11.1**

---

This bug affects every part of GUI which is wrapped with `Deploy` as well as every `Cell`/`Notebook`/whatever with option `Deployed->True`. So it will affect e.g. **all dialogs**. Keep that in mind if you care about details in your GUI.

In addition to answers the most handy **quick fix** is to add

```
BaseStyle -> {Deployed -> False, Editable -> False,  Selectable -> False}
```

instead of `Deploy` or to replace `Deployed->True`, in appropriate places.

---

Here are two small examples:

-

```
Through[{Deploy, Identity} @ Graphics @ Table[
  Tooltip[{EdgeForm@Thin, Hue[i], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2 - i, i}]}, i],
  {i, 0, 1, .1}
]]
```

[image]

-

```
Graphics[{
 Dynamic[{
  If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Red, Blue], Thickness@.05, Line[{{0, 0}, {.5, 0}}]}],
 Dynamic[{
  If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Red, Blue], Disk[{.5, 0}, .2]}]
  }, PlotRange -> {{0, .6}, {-.3, .3}}]
```

> [image]

You can put cursor over the `Disk` or `Line`. As you can see the `Disk` covers the `Line`, so you can only get:

> [image] or [image]

But as soon as we add `Deploy` (`Deploy@Graphics[...`), the `Disk` becomes transparent to the `"MouseOver"` event, and we can get the following result (with cursor on the right place):

> [image]

This behaviour is so unexpected, I'm tempted to call it a bug. This change in behaviour is huge!

In this context, `Deploy` as a quick and nice function seems to be unreliable. :/

---

The walkaround is similar like there: [Delay of events detection dependent of “MouseDown” position](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33242/5478). But I doubt the reason is the same.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thank you again :)

Comment: I can confirm this behavior on V9.0.1 running on OS X. Further, it persists even when I put the disk and line each in their own `Graphics` expression and then display the two separated graphics with `Show`. I would call this behavior a bug.

Comment: Maybe I didn't test this correctly earlier on. With OS X 10.9.1 I get the error with both V8 and V9.

Comment: I have reported this behavior to WRI tech support. I will post their response upon receiving it.

Comment: Nothing satisfactory. I got an answer saying "Just wanted to keep you posted that I have received your question and am currently working on it. ... I need to work on this a little longer to figure out the difference in behavior. I will keep you posted on what I find." After that, no follow up. Didn't think this was worth posting. Perhaps I should ping them on this.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks, good to know they are working on this. I don't know if ping will change something ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem seems to be that a `TagBox` that is generated is handled incorrectly by the front end. The `TagBox` has the form `TagBox[bigExpr, Deploy, DefaultBaseStyle -> "Deploy"]`.  In this expression the second argument `Deploy` is quite meaningless. I couldn't trace any further than this `TagBox` as I cannot see how the front end handles it.

How the kernel handles `Deploy` is not secret. You can remove the attribute `ReadProtected` from `Deploy` to see how it is handled. The definition is quite simple. It refers to `WrappersDump'WrapperToBoxes`, which always continues using the following definition

```
WrappersDump`WrapperToBoxes[Deploy[BoxForm`e_],BoxForm`fmt_]:=
TagBox[MakeBoxes[BoxForm`e,BoxForm`fmt],Deploy,DefaultBaseStyle->"Deploy"]
```

This is where the evil `TagBox` is created. The way this is coded also seems to generate some unnecessary tests, but that is a different matter.

**Workaround**

Anyway, a workaround is to never generate such `TagBox`es and generate inline cells instead. You can use `deploy` below instead of `Deploy`.

```
deploy /: MakeBoxes[deploy[expr_], form_] := 
 Cell[BoxData[MakeBoxes[expr, form]], Selectable -> False, Deployed -> True]
```

This then gives you what you want

```
deploy@
 Graphics[{Dynamic[{If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Red, Blue], 
     Thickness@.05, Line[{{0, 0}, {.5, 0}}]}], 
   Dynamic[{If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Red, Blue], 
     Disk[{.5, 0}, .2]}]}, PlotRange -> {{0, .6}, {-.3, .3}}]
```

It is basically doing what you were doing you were doing yourself :), maybe you thought of inline cells already.

By the way, because the definitions of `Deploy` are known, redefining `Deploy` by `Unprotect`ing it should be quite predictable. Note that not every symbol that is `ReadProtected` shows all of its code, but I think `Deploy` does.

Comment: I wasn't aware I could do this :) I have to read "Notebooks" tutorial one time :) Thanks :)

Comment: @Kuba no problem, I hope the solution will not have unexpected side effects, e.g. when non rectangular clickable things overlap. Time will tell I suppose :)

Answer (score 5):

**Quick fix** is to add

```
 ContentSelectable -> False, ImageSize -> Dynamic[Automatic, None]
```

to `Graphics` options. Now the it is behaving well with exeption of orange frame that appears to allow you to change `ImageSize`, which is supressed by `Dynamic[#, None]`.

---

**More generic approach**

Something strange is happening. When we set `Deployed -> True` and `Selectable -> False` for the cell it is working like one is expected. Why not with `Deployed` then?

Keep in mind it is not general solution since you can `Deploy` individual parts of the cell while this will set those options for the whole cell.

```
Composition[
  CellPrint,
  Cell[#, "Output", Deployed -> True, Selectable -> False] &,
  BoxData,
  MakeBoxes
  ][
    Graphics[
     {Dynamic[{If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Red, Blue], 
               Thickness@.05, Line[{{0, 0}, {.5, 0}}]}], 
      Dynamic[{If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Red, Blue], Disk[{.5, 0}, .2]}]}, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, .6}, {-.3, .3}}]
   ]
```

Answer (score 4):

I reported this to WRI tech support on March 9th and, finally received an answer today. As I promised in a comment to the question, here it is (somewhat edited).

> My apologies for the delay in getting back to you.
>
> Just wanted to let you know that I was unable to find a resolution for this issue and have forwarded an incident report to the development team.
>
> We will keep you posted if a resolution becomes available in a future release of Mathematica. Sorry we could not offer a more satisfactory resolution.

It appears to me the tech support person who handled my report thought that Kuba's finding was a correctable error or had a simple work around and tried to come up with a solution, but failed, and finally reported the problem to the developers as a bug, which is what my report suggested.

Comment: m_goldberg, thank you for your efforts to reach out to support. I hope support is becoming more and more aware that your emails are a valuable source of information.