# Black Ovals appeared in my Mathematica notebook

Tags: mathematical-optimization, formatting

I copied and pasted something from another Mathematic notebook and started getting the same black ovals seen in this question:

[Colored marks appearing in notebook input text?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64102/colored-marks-appearing-in-notebook-input-text)

The suggestion to turn off the highlighting has not gotten rid of these black verticla ovals though. any help?

Comment: Try turning off "Flash cursor tracker when insertion point moves unexpectedly" in the preferences.

Comment: I have marked this as a duplicate because there is no indication that this is a separate problem.  I have had this happen too, in 10.0.0, 10.0.1, and 10.0.2 unfortunately.  However a restart has always (temporarily) solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

saving and reopening my notebook got rid of them