# Floating highlighting bug

Tags: front-end, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and not fixed up to 10.2**

At some random point in time the highlighting does not disappear any more. By highlighting I mean transparent boxes appearing for

- find feature indicating found object,
- cursor highlighting once you go back to previous line and
- bracket matching when one adds the closing bracket.

It does not start right away with a new notebook but appears on some random point. After this point in time every highlighting remains. They do not disappear on window resize, minimize, maximize or any other event I have tried to trigger. Only solution is to reopen the notebook.

I have observed the problem on number of PCs I use in lab all having different versions of ***Mathematica* 10.0.x** and **Windows 7 or 8, 32 or 64 bit**. It is still present with ***Mathematica* 10.1**.

I did look through all *Mathematica* v10 bugs reported here with front-end tags and I did not find it reported yet. As we have it on many PCs I must not be the only one experiencing it. Has anyone found a workaround, which makes the disappear?

I have not jet reported to Wolfram as I have not figured out a way of reproducing it. But for me and my colleagues here it happens daily.

Here is a screenshot:
[image: screenshot describing the frontend bug of Mathetmatica v10]

**Edit**
Now I see it has been reported before: [Coloured marks appearing in notebook input text](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64102/colored-marks-appearing-in-notebook-input-text?rq=1)

**Edit 2**
The bug is still there in 10.2 although it did take me long time to get it again:
[image]

Comment: Awesome, just awesome. I highlighted your system specs a bit because this is vitally important to the question. Nevertheless, I would report it to WRI. Give a `SystemInformation[]` notebook for every computer where this happens and various screenshots. They can probably provide you with things you can try to narrow the bug down.

Comment: @halirutan I've seen this too, couple of times in different notebooks. Even new ones with two cells.

Comment: @Kuba Then there is more reason to report it. Maybe a two people bug is already the critical line where WRI starts investigating. Especially, since it happens on Windows (and not on Linux).

Comment: @halirutan I feel like this issue was asked about ealier but I can't find it.

Comment: I have seen this two or three times as well over the last year.

Comment: @Kuba I found the other topic now.

http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64102/colored-marks-appearing-in-notebook-input-text?rq=1

Comment: As the other question has no answers I can not mark as duplicate.

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate.  I interpret your comment above as meaning this is the action you felt was appropriate, and I agree.