# Tooltip/EventHandler misaligned with scaled graphics primitives they wrap

Tags: graphics, bugs, front-end, gui-construction

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and persists through 12.2**

It affects all event based wrappers for affected primitives. E.g. `EventHandler`. Which makes it a big limiting factor.

For more crowded plots it can be really devastating.

If you find that problem a serious one, **please report it too**!

---

Problem reproduced on Win10 with V10.4.1, V11.0.0

> A support case with the identification [CASE:3698391] was created
>
> [...] There appears to be an issue with Tooltip in your second graph. It has been reported on your behalf, to our developers. [...]

---

Areas covered by `Tooltip` are incorrect when we `Scale` primitives those Tooltips are wrapping:

```
data1 = RandomReal[250, 250];
data2 = RandomReal[250, 250];

hist = Histogram[<|"d1" -> data1, "d2" -> data2|>, Frame -> True, 
  ImageSize -> 600];


Row[{hist, 
  Graphics[Scale[hist[[1]], {1, 1/250}, {1, 0}], 
   AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 600]}, 
Spacer[20]]
```

Old gif but reduced code gives the same issue.
[image]

As you can see, in the right, scaled plot, Tooltips are triggered outside rectangles. For more complicated visualizations it makes them useless.

It affects `EventHandlers`, `CurrentValue["MouseOver"]` etc. too. `ScalingTransform` behaves the same.

Any insights? Workarounds?

Comment: Reproduced with versions 8.0.4, 10.4.1 and 11.0.0 on Win7 x64.

Comment: Instead of scaling coordinates in graphics primitives you can of course scale the data before generating them, but you knew that.

Comment: @masterxilo yep, the background is that I want to scale it dynamically and replotting is too expensive.