# Allow multiple GUI elements to react dynamically to interaction with a single element

Tags: graphics, performance-tuning, front-end, dynamic, gui-construction

I was looking at how to reproduce the *interactivity* [in this visualization](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607999) (the layout can be done [like this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55367/12)).  Hovering a node with the mouse highlights all edges that are connected to it.  How can we reproduce this type of interactivity in Mathematica and still preserve good performance?

If there is a single notebook element which needs to react to interaction, there are usually direct ways to do that, without the need for intermediate variables.  For example:

```
Graphics[{Dynamic@Style[Disk[], If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Red, Black]]}]
```

But in the example linked above, edges must highlight in response to hovering vertices and there's a many-to-many relationship between these two types of objects.  Each edge must respond to hovering two different vertices.  Hovering a vertex must highlight multiple different edges.  How can we access the state of one type of object (vertex) while computing the dynamic style of an edge?

I tried two approaches:

1. The first one uses a boolean vector in a `DynamicModule` to store the hover state of vertices.  This is then read by the styling of edges.  This approach is not fast enough.
2. The second one uses [`MouseAnnotation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MouseAnnotation.html).  This is considerably slower than the first one.

Can we make it faster?

---

Let's make a graph:

```
n = 80; (* number of vertices *)
names = Range[n]; (* vertex names, in this case they are simply the vertex indices *)
pts = AssociationThread[names -> N@CirclePoints[n]]; (* vertex coordinates *)
edges = RandomSample[Subsets[names, {2}], 250]; (* graph edges *)
```

---

With boolean vector in DynamicModule:

```
DynamicModule[{state = ConstantArray[False, n]}, 
   Deploy@Graphics[
    {
      With[{pt1 = pts[#1], pt2 = pts[#2]},
        {Dynamic@If[state[[#1]] || state[[#2]], Red, Black], Line[{pt1, pt2}]} 
      ]& @@@ edges,

      PointSize[0.025], 
      With[{pt = pts[#]},
        {Dynamic@If[state[[#]], Red, Black], 
         EventHandler[Point[pt], 
           {"MouseEntered" :> (state[[#]] = True), 
            "MouseExited"  :> (state[[#]] = False)}
         ]
        } 
      ]& /@ names
    }, 
   ImageSize -> Large]]
```

---

With [`MouseAnnotation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MouseAnnotation.html).  Warning: this may temporarily freeze the front end!

```
Deploy@Graphics[
  {
   With[{pt1 = pts[#1], pt2 = pts[#2]},
    {Dynamic@If[MouseAnnotation[] === #1 || MouseAnnotation[] === #2, Red, Black], 
     Line[{pt1, pt2}]} 
   ]& @@@ edges,

   PointSize[0.025],
   With[{pt = pts[#]},
     Annotation[
       Dynamic@Style[Point[pt], If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Red, Black]], 
       #, 
       "Mouse"
     ] 
   ]& /@ names
  },
  ImageSize -> Large
]
```

---

The graph size in this example is not excessive.  It is about the same as the vertex and edge counts of `ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "LesMiserables"}]` (77, 254), which I used while working on the [layout part](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55367/12).

Comment: off topic note: Don't use `Deploy` when events handling matters: [Passing mouse related events broken by Deploy](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43672/5478)

Comment: Sorry about all the edits.  I made mistakes at the beginning and it's no longer possible to delete an *answer*, finish editing and undelete. It's finished now.

Comment: In case you are interested in doing this kind of stuff more often and in a more user friendly manner, I started this: https://github.com/kubaPod/DynamicObjects, I didn't add any release yet but will after weekend.

Comment: Done https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/174792/5478

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
n = 120;
names = Range[n];
pts = AssociationThread[names -> N@CirclePoints[n]];
edges = RandomSample[Subsets[names, {2}], 250];
```

There are two reasons why `Dynamic` scales badly:

- there is no (documented) way to tell a "DynamicObject" to update, one can only count on dependency tree which is created.
- one can track only Symbols

The second one implies that big lists/associations will always update each `Dynamic` they are mentioned in. Even when each one only cares about a specific value.

Additionaly symbols renaming/management tools in Mathematica are surprisingly limited/not suited for a type of job I am about to show. The following solution may be unreadable at first sight.

The idea is to create symbols: `state1`, `state2`,... instead of using `state[[1]]`. This way only specific `Dynamic` will be triggered when needed, not all of `state[[..]]`.

```
DynamicModule[{},
 Graphics[{
   (
    ToExpression[
      "{sA:=state" <> ToString[#] <> ", sB:=state" <> ToString[#2] <> "}",
      StandardForm, 
      Hold
    ] /. Hold[spec_] :> With[spec, 
       {  Dynamic @ If[TrueQ[sA || sB], Red, Black], 
          Line[{pts[#1], pts[#2]}]
       }
    ]
   ) & @@@ edges
   ,
   PointSize[0.025],
   (
    ToExpression[
      "{sA:=state" <> ToString[#] <> "}", 
      StandardForm, 
      Hold
    ] /. Hold[spec_] :> With[spec, 
       { Dynamic @ If[TrueQ[sA], Red, Black], 
         EventHandler[ Point @ pts[#], 
           {"MouseEntered" :> (sA = True), "MouseExited" :> (sA = False)}
         ]
       }
    ]
   ) & /@ names
  }, 
  ImageSize -> Large]
 ]
```

[image]

Ok, we can go even further. This code still communicates with the Kernel while it doesn't have to:

```
ClearAll["state*"]
ToExpression[
 "{" <> StringJoin[
   Riffle[Table["state" <> ToString[i] <> "=False", {i, n}], ","]] <> 
  "}",
 StandardForm,
 Function[vars,
  DynamicModule[vars, 
   Graphics[{(ToExpression[
          "{sA:=state" <> ToString[#] <> ", sB:=state" <> 
           ToString[#2] <> "}", StandardForm, Hold] /. 
         Hold[spec_] :> With[spec, {RawBoxes@DynamicBox[

              FEPrivate`If[
               FEPrivate`SameQ[FEPrivate`Or[sA, sB], True], 
               RGBColor[1, 0, 1], RGBColor[0, 1, 0]]], 
            Line[{pts[#1], pts[#2]}]}]) & @@@ edges, 
     PointSize[
      0.025], (ToExpression["{sA:=state" <> ToString[#] <> "}", 
          StandardForm, Hold] /. 
         Hold[spec_] :> 
          With[spec, {RawBoxes@
             DynamicBox[
              FEPrivate`If[SameQ[sA, True], RGBColor[1, 0, 1], 
               RGBColor[0, 1, 0]]], 
            EventHandler[
             Point@pts[#], {"MouseEntered" :> FEPrivate`Set[sA, True],
               "MouseExited" :> FEPrivate`Set[sA, False]}]}]) & /@ 
      names}, ImageSize -> Large]]
  ,
  HoldAll
  ]
 ]
```

Finally something neat completely FrontEnd side :)

Comment: Heya Kuba, I have refactored your code in a community wiki answer, mainly in an attempt to understand what is going on. I have removed `RawBoxes` heads and `SameQ`. Maybe take a look?

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Thanks! Didn't know that `Graphics` accepts pure boxes. `SameQ` was a substitute of `TrueQ` which was just in case.

Comment: I didn't know it accepted `RawBoxes` so I just figured: "What if I remove this?" :P. Not much depth there ;)

Comment: probably [the fiver game](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120959/4330) can also have a Front End only solution. That might be a nice challenge

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom FrontEnd side is tempting but I often get discouraged quickly due to the lack of documentation :)

Comment: so, I made the fiver game Front End only version [(link)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128846/4330)

Comment: Heya Kuba, have fun at the WTC. No need to answer as you are probably busy, but...

Comment: I was wondering if you knew what the limitations of the Wolfram Programming Cloud were when dealing with `DynamicModule` objects. Simple things seem to work there.

Comment: @jacob do you have specific aspects in mind?

Comment: just wondering why the examples here (Front End only versions, also the other one I linked to) as well as some adaptations I tried, don't work.

Comment: @jacob this is a different front end and it does not have a kernel so feprivate or frontend contexts do not exists/matter, and apparently they are not translated to client side js either. There is js api for cloud objects but nothing that would alow you to create completely client side ui, yet.

Comment: yeah, I also thought ``FEPrivate` `` things wouldn't work. That was one thing I changed in my adaptations. I also tried using `Dynamic` instead of `DynamicBox`, but I still couldn't get it to work unfortunately.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a refactor of Kuba's wonderful answer. I hope it may help somebody understand the order in which things are evaluated better. This version should also be resistant against conflicting symbol names, though perhaps it would have been easier to achieve that using contexts. A few things that I thought might be unnecessary have been removed.

```
n = 100;
names = Permute[Range[10*n], RandomPermutation[10*n]][[;; n]];
pts = AssociationThread[names -> N@CirclePoints[n]];
edgesIndices = 
  RandomSample[Subsets[Range[n], {2}], Quotient[n Log[n], 2]];
edges = Map[names[[#]] &, edgesIndices, {2}];

heldStates = 
  Join @@ (ToExpression["state" <> ToString[#] , InputForm, Hold] & /@
      names);
dynModVars = List @@@ Hold@Evaluate[Set @@@ Thread[{
        heldStates,
        Hold @@ ConstantArray[False, n]
        }, Hold]];
preMapThread = Apply[List,
   Hold@Evaluate[
     Join[heldStates[[#]] & /@ Transpose@edgesIndices, Transpose@edges]],
   {1, 2}];
preAppMap = Thread[{heldStates, Hold @@ names}, Hold];
edgeDisplayerMaker = Function[
   {sA, sB, name1, name2},
   {DynamicBox[
     If[FEPrivate`Or[sA, sB], RGBColor[1, 0, 1], RGBColor[0, 1, 0]]], 
    Line[{pts[name1], pts[name2]}]}
   , HoldAll];
interactivePointMaker = Function[
   {sA, name},
   {DynamicBox[If[sA, RGBColor[1, 0, 1], RGBColor[0, 1, 0]]], 
    EventHandler[
     Point@pts[name], {"MouseEntered" :> FEPrivate`Set[sA, True], 
      "MouseExited" :> FEPrivate`Set[sA, False]}]}, HoldAll];
```

Perhaps the structure of the `DynamicModule` is now a little clearer.

```
DynamicModule @@ {
  Unevaluated @@ dynModVars
  ,
  Unevaluated@
   Graphics[{
     MapThread @@ {
       edgeDisplayerMaker,
       Unevaluated @@ preMapThread},
     PointSize[0.025],
     List @@ interactivePointMaker @@@ preAppMap
     }, ImageSize -> Large]}
```

Comment: I will study it soon, I wish I had such ease in assembling held expressions ;)

Comment: @Kuba Ha! I figured after this answer that maybe I would try to use Contexts next instead of wrapping everything in Hold from the get-go, but your comment is motivating :). I like held expressions, and code == data and all that :).

Comment: that is the best way in this case, context are useful for other things, you never know what's on $ContextPath ;)

Comment: @Kuba Hm, I think I made a mistake that I was not punished for (maybe the code is still ok), in that I intended that `preMapThread` and `preAppMap` would be evaluated earlier, so that they are in the lexical scope of `DynamicModule`. Strange that this somehow is not necessary, I'll look into that later.

Comment: still haven't studied it and don't know what do you mean :)

Comment: @Kuba no problem :), it was just a bit of a warning, I don't want to waste anybody's time :).

Comment: What's the reason to prefer ``FEPrivate`Or`` and ``FEPrivate`If`` over `Or` and `If`?  Seems I can use the later without performance drop.  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Hey @QuantumDot, the idea is that ``FEPrivate`Or`` (etc) can be evaluated by the Front End, so that no communication with the kernel is needed, which is supposed to increase performance. Linksnooper can be used to monitor the communication between the front end and the kernel. I just looked at [another answer of mine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128846/4330) and it seems that `If` can be evaluated by the Front End. I probably didn't use Linksnooper for my answer here and maybe it was an incorrect guess that ``FEPrivate`If`` would make things faster.