# How to build a movie of a chart in which Tooltip is used to display the labels associated with the points on the chart

Tags: graphics, animation

I first need to build the following chart to explain what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
data = {{"29-1141", 186, 112}, {"41-2031", 123, 92},
       {"41-1011", 65, 404}, {"43-4051", 108, 646},
       {"31-1014", 643, 246}, {"49-9071", 356, 363},
       {"43-1011", 543, 381}, {"43-5081", 268, 674},
       {"53-3032", 416, 653}, {"37-3011", 514, 428},
       {"37-2012", 501, 58}, {"33-9032", 441, 598},
       {"35-2014", 633, 138}, {"29-2061", 414, 590},
       {"53-3033", 98, 155}, {"35-3031", 179, 431},
       {"49-3023", 93, 623}, {"35-3021", 37, 578},
       {"41-2011",256, 237}, {"37-2011", 302, 50},
       {"47-1011", 518, 2}, {"11-9111", 313, 294},
       {"31-9092", 698, 136}, {"43-3031", 608, 610},
       {"43-6013", 562, 515}, {"13-2011", 415, 327},
       {"21-1093", 191, 72}, {"41-4012", 212, 92},
       {"41-3031", 546, 418}, {"31-1011", 591, 49},
       {"47-2031", 405, 526}, {"41-3021", 191, 297},
       {"15-1151", 442, 445}, {"43-6011", 118, 185},
       {"49-1011", 472, 402}, {"53-7062", 348, 552},
       {"43-4171", 409, 396}, {"43-6014", 348, 247},
       {"53-1031", 629, 59}, {"47-2061", 589, 534},
       {"27-1026", 22, 377}, {"29-1069", 445, 74},
       {"49-9021", 647, 539}, {"43-9061", 25, 543},
       {"11-1021", 19, 165}, {"41-1012", 482, 199},
       {"29-1062", 1, 68}, {"43-4081", 217, 112},
       {"41-3099", 663, 66}, {"11-3031", 329, 392},
       {"53-7061", 357, 515}, {"35-2021", 488, 245},
       {"31-9091", 318, 679}, {"51-1011", 650, 349},
       {"11-9051", 38, 145}, {"53-3031", 166, 691},
       {"39-9021", 561, 127}, {"39-5012", 665, 362},
       {"47-2111", 397, 532}, {"43-3071", 326, 271},
       {"29-2034", 361, 450}, {"35-9011", 12, 366},
       {"29-1123", 16, 211}, {"15-1142", 162, 662},
       {"11-2021", 520, 164}, {"29-2031", 339, 619},
       {"25-2011", 263, 564}, {"41-4011", 551, 301},
       {"29-2055", 76, 549}, {"29-2052", 285, 640},
       {"13-2072", 370, 542}, {"35-2012", 512, 547},
       {"11-2022", 130, 154}, {"15-1132", 188, 274},
       {"13-2052", 338, 587}, {"15-1199", 455, 5},
       {"35-9031", 595, 472}, {"17-2051", 648, 481},
       {"11-9199", 430, 189}, {"39-3091", 29, 396},
       {"47-2152", 412, 342}, {"29-1122", 582, 20},
       {"11-9141", 276, 4}, {"25-2021", 666, 617},
       {"15-1134", 236, 334}, {"37-1011", 407, 664},
       {"29-1063", 260, 278}, {"49-3031", 161, 354},
       {"41-9022", 185, 144}, {"41-9041", 551, 628},
       {"25-2031", 529, 505}, {"29-2071", 548, 296},
       {"29-1127", 373, 124}, {"21-1023", 473, 71},
       {"29-1067", 489, 569}, {"29-1071", 539, 277},
       {"11-3121", 390, 348}, {"11-9021", 634, 20},
       {"53-3041", 589, 258}, {"49-3021", 47, 206}};
```

Next:

```
minx = Round[Min[data[[All, 2]]]];
maxx = Round[Max[data[[All, 2]]]];
dx = Round[Subdivide[minx, maxx, 3]];

miny = Round[Min[data[[All, 3]]]];
maxy = Round[Max[data[[All, 3]]]];
dy = Round[Subdivide[miny, maxy, 3]];

gridpts = Tuples[{dx, dy}];

 regions = {Rectangle[gridpts[[1]], gridpts[[6]]], 
  Rectangle[gridpts[[5]], gridpts[[10]]], 
  Rectangle[gridpts[[9]], gridpts[[14]]], 
  Rectangle[gridpts[[2]], gridpts[[7]]], 
  Rectangle[gridpts[[6]], gridpts[[11]]], 
  Rectangle[gridpts[[10]], gridpts[[15]]], 
  Rectangle[gridpts[[3]], gridpts[[8]]], 
  Rectangle[gridpts[[7]], gridpts[[12]]], 
  Rectangle[gridpts[[11]], gridpts[[16]]]};

colors = {Magenta, Orange, Cyan, Red, Blue, Green, LightGray, Yellow, 
   Black};

pts = Table[
    Select[data, #[[{2, 3}]] \[Element] r &], {r, 
     regions}] /. {} -> {{}};

addTooltips = 
  Table[If[# === {}, Style[{0, 0}, Opacity[0]], 
       Tooltip[#[[{2, 3}]], #[[1]]]] & /@ p, {p, #}] &;

chart = ListPlot[addTooltips@pts, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> colors, 
  GridLines -> {dx, dy}, Axes -> False, 
  PlotRange -> {{minx, maxx}, {miny, maxy}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

If you now sweep the chart with your mouse' s cursor over the points, you will be able to see the labels associated with each point on the chart; thanks to
the Tooltip used for this purpose.

My question is; WITHOUT using Adobo Photoshop or any other "gif builder"
software; how can one build the following movie WITHIN MATHEMATICA;
so that the movie can be exported from Mathematica; into your working
directory; in gif format?

[image: Gif Movie:]

Thank you!

Comment: That will be very hard to do: There is no way (as far as I know) to get a "screenshot" of what the frontend displays - you can get an image of the plot itself, but any tooltips/cursor will be missing. If you *really* wanted to, you could [draw your own mouse pointer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18136/36508) together with the tooltip, record mouse movements (using [`MousePosition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MousePosition.html)), and render everything into a movie. But I really don't see a good reason for this - it is way more work to set up and use, and way slower

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option for cycling through the labels.

```
frames = Table[
   ListPlot[
    Join[pts[[All, All, {2, 3}]], {{Callout[p[[{2, 3}]], p[[1]], Below, 
        Appearance -> "Frame"]}}], Frame -> True, 
    PlotStyle -> Join[colors, {{Opacity[0]}}], GridLines -> {dx, dy}, 
    Axes -> False, PlotRange -> {{minx, maxx}, {miny, maxy}}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1, BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]], {p, data}];

Export["regionsplot2.gif", frames, "AnimationRepetitions" -> Infinity, "DisplayDurations" -> 3]
```

[image]

Or for just pointing to a subset of the data, for example 20 random points:

`randompts = RandomSample[data, 20];`

And replace the `Table` iterator with `{p, randompts}`.

Comment: Thank you @MelaGo for your amazing answer! I wanted to "film" some points of interest; i.e.; the gray points (Low Ads -High Openings); the black points (High Ads - High Openings) and the Cyan points (High Ads - Low Openings) using the mouse cursor.  But, I have opted instead to generate the list of industries corresponding to those three scenarios and export them as Excel workbooks.  I accept your answer; and thank you for solving a "real life problem" for us (plural because I hope this example will help many others with similar tasks).

Comment: @GilmarRodriguezPierluissi You're welcome. Btw if you wanted to point out one region, for example just the grey points, you could do so by replacing the Table iterator with `{p, pts[[7]]}`.

Comment: Thank you @MelaGo for showing us how to isolate one region by replacing the Table iterator with {p, pts[[k]]} where k is element of {1,...,9}.